# Annoyingly high number of network connection failure popups per second

Tags: wireless

This post is not a duplicate of other posts that ask how to debug wifi issues. I know my wifi connectivity is not superb, so it sometimes disconnects and I have to start tethering/turn wifi off and on again.

However, I face a problem every time network connection goes does. Specifically, the popup "Activation of network connection failed" pops up at least twenty times within two seconds. That's a lot! It annoys me as my computer hangs completely for those two seconds the popups happen. And it clearly isn't helpful for me as well to know the same thing ten times a second.

Is there anyway to rate-limit this popup? Or any other way to fix this issue?

---

Ubuntu 18.04.2 with `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

Comment: the popups right now have litterally 0 code that govern their "need to be shown" every single "call" will show. it's shit but I'm sure canonical are on it as it's annoying not just for this edge case. I get about 7 of these for my network printer telling me it's available now evertime somone in the office uses it. It's part of gnome3. this is probably why it hasn't been tackled yet

Comment: @Jeremy31 Sorry, no matches found. I believe you meant something other than `[[:alnum:]]`?

Comment: The entire command includes everything from grep to *

Comment: @Jeremy31 Sorry, still nothing.

Comment: Hi I put `[[:alnum:]]` in double quotes and got this output for the modprobe.d thing. https://pastebin.com/Z2BY6aYC Is this what you expected? @Jeremy31

Comment: If it is an HP you need to set the ant_sel=2 for rtl8723de module as the issue is likely poor reception